# Scheduling localhost serverless cron: The model could not be resolved in registry

Tags: express, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm hosting an ExpressJS/NodeJS API on AWS Lambda with Serverless framework. The API uses Knex.js and Bookshelf.js ORM.

I want to test scheduling a cron job locally. I'm using `serverless-offline-scheduler` to do this.

**Question**: My API runs fine if I call it from my client, but if I call a function via serverless scheduler, it complains that no models are in the registry. Why is this? I've already definitely included all necessary Models at the top of the OrderService.js file.

```
{
    "errorMessage": "The model User could not be resolved from the registry plugin.",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Error: The model User could not be resolved from the registry plugin.",
        "    at new ModelNotResolved (/Users/danielturcotte/Sites/d2c/api_v4/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/plugins/registry.js:70:133)",
```

**Serverless.yml:**

```
functions:
  app:
    handler: handler.handler
    events: ...
  dequeue:
    handler: ./services/OrderService.dequeue // Call dequeue function
    events:
      - schedule: rate(1 minute)
```

The handler calls `root/services/OrderService.dequeue` function, which contains

```
...
const dequeue = async function() {
    await checkQueuedOrders();
};

module.exports = {
    dequeue,
};
```

In my `knexService.js` file, I register Bookshelf models to the registry to remove circular dependencies:

```
const knexfile = require('./knexfile');
const config = require('./environment');

const environment = config.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const knex = require('knex')(knexfile[environment]);

knex.client.pool.numPendingCreates();

const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin('registry'); // Resolve circular dependencies with relations
bookshelf.plugin('visibility');
bookshelf.plugin('pagination');

module.exports.knex = knex;
module.exports.bookshelf = bookshelf;
```

Comment: How are you using and defining these models?